# Algorithm to split decimal number to integer and floating

Tags: algorithms

If x is a decimal number, how can we split its integer number and its floating number?

For instances, if x = 3.2 I want y to be 3 and z to be 0.2

What would be the easiest algorithm to do that? I try many direction but useless and now I'm confuse.

Many thanks if you help

Comment: You mean that you want to represent the integer part of a number mathematically?

Comment: Yes, is it indeed difficult? Or it is just too hard for me?

Comment: Are you asking for a simple method like @mathlove's answer or are you trying to write an algorithm to do it?

Comment: Actually I want to learn to write an algorithm upon that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a floor function as the following :
$$\lfloor x\rfloor$$
is represented as the integer part of a number $x$ when $x\ge0$.

For example, $\lfloor 3.2\rfloor=3.$

When $x\lt 0,$ $\lfloor x\rfloor+1$ gives you the integer part of a number $x$.

For example, if you want to show the integer part of $x=-3.2$, then $\lfloor -3.2\rfloor+1=-3.$

Comment: Note that this does not work for the OP's task when $x<0$.

Comment: Oh, you are right. I need to edit.

Comment: Yeah I know, we can easily find the floor number using programming language's function such as floor function. I need to do it using step by step math instruction, sorry about that

Comment: Oh, you should have written so. Anyway, never mind.

Comment: @user2298766:  what do you mean by "step by step math instruction"?  The floor function is a fine mathematical function.

Comment: I mean, inside that function should be a conditional, looping and math expression, I want to know what inside that function well in math, sorry kind of crazy question